# Spring OAuth2 on Android Exception: Didn't find class "javax.xml.transform.stax.StAXSource" on path: DexPathList

Tags: java, android, spring, oauth-2.0, dependencies

I try to make an android client for a server using spring's OAuth2 dependency. The problem is that when I call this constructor:

```
OAuth2RestTemplate oAuthRestTemplate = new Auth2RestTemplate(resourceDetails);
```

I get this Exception:

```
Didn't find class "javax.xml.transform.stax.StAXSource" on path: DexPathList
```

I use Android Studio which uses gradle and I include the OAuth2 dependency like this:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2:2.3.0.RC1'
    ...
}
```

In a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40845926/class-load-exception-when-using-restservice-java-lang-classnotfoundexception), the accepted answer suggests to include the Spring rest-template dependency (`compile 'org.springframework.android:spring-android-rest-template:1.0.1.RELEASE'`) but when I do this I get another error that I have also posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49020955/rest-android-client-using-spring-and-oauth2-error-dexarchivemergerexception-una).

I believe that the Spring rest-template dependency should not be included because it may already be imported by the Spring OAuth dependency. Is it true? And if it is, how can I solve the fact that another class (`javax.xml.transform.stax.StAXSource`) can't be found? I think the reason that this class can't be found is because I am on android which uses its own implementation of JDK as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36757089/how-to-use-javax-xml-transform-stax-in-android-studio) suggests.

If anyone could help me solve this problem, it would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that the other dependency was needed (spring-android-rest-template dependency), and I had to put both of them and also exclude the duplicate modules. I did it like this:

```
compile('org.springframework.android:spring-android-rest-template:2.0.0.M3') {
    exclude module: 'spring-android-core'
}

compile('org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2:2.3.0.RC1'){
    exclude module: 'spring-web'
}
```